# How can I replace the NULL values in dataframe with Average of Forward and backward fill?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've just started using R and i'm trying to replace the NULl values in each columns by the average of forward and backward values. Below is the sample dataframe that has couple of null values

```
  A      B     C  
  1      1    2000
  2      NA   NA
  3      4    5000
  4      NA   NA
  5      7    8000
```

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
  A      B      C 
  1      1     2000
  2     2.5    3500
  3      4     5000
  4     5.5    6500
  5      7     8000
```

***tidyr*** seems to do half of the work `df %>% fill("A",.direction = c("down"))` but how can i replace the average of the forward and the backward values ?

Comment: You should learn that NA and NULL are not the same in the R language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `na.approx`

```
library(zoo)
df1[-1] <- na.approx(df1[-1])
df1
#  A   B    C
#1 1 1.0 2000
#2 2 2.5 3500
#3 3 4.0 5000
#4 4 5.5 6500
#5 5 7.0 8000
```

Or with `lapply`

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], na.approx)
```

---

Or used along with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, na.approx)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, na.approx), .SDcols = 2:3]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = 1:5, B = c(1L, NA, 4L, NA, 7L), C = c(2000L, 
NA, 5000L, NA, 8000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```